# How to change color dynamically?

Tags: plotting, dynamic, color, filling

I am new to `Mathematica` and want to change the `FillingStyle` Dynamically in this `Plot`. I want that when I pick a color from the "Color" then, it should dynamically change in the Sin plot.

```
 a = RGBColor[1, 2, 0]
 Row[{Button["<<Color>>", a = SystemDialogInput["Color"]], 
Evaluate[Plot[Sin[m], {m, -Pi, Pi}, Filling -> Bottom, 
FillingStyle -> Dynamic[a]]]}]
```

I am able to pick a color but the plot is not changing dynamically. But, it changes when I am executing it again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The expression `FillingStyle -> value` is not preserved in the output `Graphics` expression of `Plot`, therefore it cannot be changed after-the-fact in that fashion.  Instead you need to regenerate the plot when the value of `a` changes, meaning that `Dynamic` needs to surround `Plot`:

```
a = RGBColor[1, 2, 0]
Row[{Button["<<Color>>", a = SystemDialogInput["Color"]], 
  Dynamic @ Plot[Sin[m], {m, -Pi, Pi}, Filling -> Bottom, FillingStyle -> a]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: See my answer for how to do it without recalculating the plot.

Comment: @ssch Strangely despite your comment I only saw your answer now. Belated +1.

Answer (score 8):

In case someone with a possibly slow to generate plot want to do this it is possible without recalculating the plot.

Looking at the `GraphicsComplex` part of the plot:

```
p = Plot[Sin[m], {m, -Pi, Pi}, Filling -> Bottom, FillingStyle -> Blue];
p[[1]]
(* GraphicsComplex[{{-3.14159, -1.28228*10^-7}, ... }}, ..., RGBColor[0, 0, 1]...] *)
```

One can guess that the `RGBColor` part is replaceable

```
a = RGBColor[0, 0, 1];
p = Plot[Sin[m], {m, -Pi, Pi}, Filling -> Bottom, 
   FillingStyle -> a]/.a->Dynamic[a];

Row[{Button["<<Color>>", a = SystemDialogInput["Color"]], 
  p}]
```

[image: plot]

Looks a bit odd with the blue line so lets change `PlotStyle` as well. Note that even with a very slow function the plot can be regenerated instantly:

```
c = RGBColor[0, 0, 1];(*Initial color*)
p = Plot[Pause[0.01]; Sin[m], {m, -Pi, Pi}, Filling -> Bottom, 
   FillingStyle -> c, PlotStyle -> c] /. c -> Dynamic[c];

Column[{ColorSlider[Dynamic[c]], p}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Or you could just use Manipulate:

```
Manipulate[
   Plot[Sin[m], {m,-Pi,Pi}, Filling -> Bottom, FillingStyle->color],
  {color,RGBColor[1,2,0]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**PaneSelector**

```
 Column[{PaneSelector[{False -> 
   Panel[Style["filling color...", "Subsection", FontColor -> Dynamic[color]]], 
   True -> ColorSlider[Dynamic[color],  AppearanceElements -> "SwatchSpectrum"]},
   Dynamic[CurrentValue["MouseOver"]]],
 Dynamic@Plot[ x Cos[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> 500,
    Filling -> Axis,  FillingStyle -> color]}]
```

[image]

**Overlay**

```
Dynamic@Overlay[{PaneSelector[{False -> 
      Plot[x Cos[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> 500, 
       Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> color], 
     True -> ColorSlider[Dynamic@color, AppearanceElements -> "SwatchSpectrum"]}, 
    CurrentValue["MouseOver"]], 
   Plot[x Cos[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> 500, Filling -> Axis,
     FillingStyle -> color]}, All, 1]
```

[image]

Comment: I answered this question in the most simple way possible (feeling that was probably most helpful to the author) and never returned to it. Nice to see that others took it deeper, even if I only notice now.