# How to dynamically toggle curves on/off in a crowded Plot?

Tags: plotting, dynamic

When multiple curves appear in a single plot, it is useful to interactively turn certain curves on or off to visually compare smaller numbers of curves.  It is trivial to put a quick dynamic together, as in this toy example

```
funcs = {Sin[x], Cos[x], Tanh[x]}; 
checked = ltexts = {"sin", "cos", "tanh"}; 
Column[{TogglerBar[Dynamic[checked], ltexts], 
   Dynamic[Block[{sel}, 
     sel = Sort[checked /. Thread[ltexts -> Range[Length[ltexts]]]]; 
      Plot[funcs[[sel]], {x, 0, 3*Pi}, PlotLegends -> ltexts[[sel]]]]]}]
```

[image: Trivial example of curve toggling, output from the code above]

This approach, is a one-off solution.  I am looking for a more elegant solution that can be applied to any plot, with a user interface that is a natural to the problem.  The buttonbar above the plot is not a natural interface. Clicking on the curve or legend would be a natural action to toggle a curve's visibility.

I intend to answer my own question, which I humbly propose as a reusable solution, but I would like to ask the community for improvements or enhancements.

Comment: @Nasser Perhaps, but the buttons just seem kludgy.  There is a Tuftian elegance in reusing the "ink" already on the "page" by dual-purposing the legend.

Comment: Just for completeness, you can also use [FlipView](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FlipView.html) to toggle through plots (with or without control, even automatically), but only one at time.

Comment: @ Daniel W: I like buttons better than the ToolTip. May be an associated color choice also could be added. I applied your code to: NDSolve[{y''[x] - Cos[y[x]] == 0, y'[0] == .5, y[0] == 1}, 
  y, {x, 0, 3 Pi}];
Y[u_] = y[u] /. First[%]; funcs = {Y[x], Y'[x], Y''[x]};
checked = ltexts = {"Y", "Y' ", "Y'' "};
Column[{TogglerBar[Dynamic[checked], ltexts], 
  Dynamic[Block[{sel}, 
    sel = Sort[checked /. Thread[ltexts -> Range[Length[ltexts]]]];
    Plot[funcs[[sel]], {x, 0, 3*Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Purple}, 
     PlotLabel -> ltexts[[sel]]]]]}]

Comment: It looks like Sjoerd Smit put something like this on the Wolfram Function Repository. It is ```ResourceFunction["CheckboxLegended"]```. This is the most robust solution given that Daniel W's second answer doesn't work for me (12.1.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)) and Michael E2's answer is hard to change to functions other than Plot (at least, I couldn't figure it out for ListLinePlot).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was inspired by the other answers to keep working on this, and I came up with a different method that, combined with some techniques from the other answers, does everything I was originally looking for (although not fully specified in the question).

The new solution is based on using `Annotation` to tag each curve and legend text with the position of the curve within the list of curves, and using `MouseAnnotation[]` to identify which curve to switch on or off when the mouse is clicked.  Either the curve or legend text can be clicked to change the state of the curve.

Set `$PlotTogglerOpacity=0` to make the curves disappear completely, in which case click the legend text to bring it back.

As a convenience for the way I intend to use the function, I also apply the legend text as `Tooltip` on the curves.  This is optional and not necessary for the function to work, so you can remove that code if you don't like that behavior.

```
Attributes[PlotToggler] = {HoldFirst};
(* a global variable for setting the opacity of dimmed curves *)
$PlotTogglerOpacity = 0.2;
PlotToggler[plotfnc_[f_, args___, opts___?OptionQ]] :=
DynamicModule[{plot, legend, ldir, ltext, annof, annopl, fropts, dim},
(* evaluate the plot, ensuring the presence of legends *)
plot = plotfnc @@ {f, args, opts, PlotLegends -> Automatic};
(* pull the legend apart, getting the graphics directives and legend text *) 
legend = plot[[2, 1]];
ldir = legend[[1, 1]];
ltext = legend[[1, 2]];
(* annotate the curves with tooltips and mouse annotations *)
(* tooltips are optional but convenient, delete tooltip code if you wish *)
(* mouse annotations are the indicies of each curve *)
annof = Table[
Tooltip[Annotation[f[[i]], i, "Mouse"], ltext[[i]]], {i, 
 Max[Length[f], Length[ltext]]}];
(* shove mouse annotated legend text back into the legend *)
annopl = 
ReplacePart[legend, 
Join[{{1, 1} -> Sequence[]}, 
 Table[{1, 2, i} -> Annotation[ltext[[i]], i, "Mouse"], {i, 
   Length[ltext]}]]];
(* we will be hijacking PlotStyle and PlotLegends later *)
fropts = FilterRules[Flatten[{opts}], 
Except[{PlotStyle, PlotLegends}]];
(* by default, all curves are not dimmed *)
dim = Table[False, {Length[ldir]}];
EventHandler[
Dynamic[
plotfnc @@ {annof, args,
(* append a switchable low opacity to the graphics directives *)
(* found earlier *)
PlotStyle -> 
   Table[With[{i = i}, 
     Flatten[Directive[ldir[[i]], 
       If[TrueQ[dim[[i]]], Opacity[$PlotTogglerOpacity], 
        Directive[]]], 1, Directive]], {i, Length[ldir]}],
  PlotLegends -> annopl,
  fropts}, TrackedSymbols :> {dim}
],
(* when the mouse is clicked, use the mouse annotation to *)
(* identify the curve to dim *)
{"MouseClicked" :> (If[
   MatchQ[MouseAnnotation[], _Integer], 
   dim[[MouseAnnotation[]]] = ! dim[[MouseAnnotation[]]]])}
]
]
```

Known issues:

- The color sample in the legend is not clickable.
- Template legend text generated by `PlotLegends->Automatic` cannot be changed after the fact.
- Annotations do not work with `ListPlot`.  Wolfram tech support has already been informed.  Use `LineListPlot` instead.  `ListLogLinearPlot` and related functions support Annotations.

Usage:

```
PlotToggler@
 Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x], Tanh[x]}, {x, 0, 3 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Thick,
  PlotLegends -> LineLegend["Expressions"], Frame -> True]
```

[image: Output from usage example]

Answer (score 11):

This solution uses the new `PlotLegends` feature of version 9.

A natural user interaction with a plot would be to click on a curve to toggle it off, but this does not work well to toggle a curve back on, and I could not figure out how to do that anyway.  Second best is to use the legend to toggle the curve visibility.  The function `DynamicLegend` is a wrapper around any plot function, as in

```
DynamicLegend[Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x], Tanh[x]}, {x, 0, 3*Pi}, 
PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{"sin", "cos", "tanh"}], 
Frame -> True]]
```

which yields the output below, after the user has turned off the visibility of the $\cos(x)$ curve by clicking on the legend text.

[image: Output from DynamicLegend, with cos turned off]

The structure of a plot with legends is

```
Legended[Graphics[...],{Placed[LineLegend[{directives}, {legend_text}, ...]...]
```

The idea of the solution is to first evaluate the plot for the sole purpose of capturing the directives and legend_text, adding transparency switches to the directives, turning the legend_text into Togglers, then replotting with the new dynamic directives and legend_text.

```
(* Don't allow the Plot to evaluate yet *)
Attributes[DynamicLegend] = {HoldAll}; 

DynamicLegend[(plotfnc_)[f_, args___, (opts___)?OptionQ]] := 
Module[{plot},
(* evaluate the plot *) 
plot = plotfnc @@ {f, args, opts}; 
(* if it does not have a legend, there is nothing to do *)
If[ !MatchQ[plot, _Legended], Return[plot]];

DynamicModule[{
(* get the directives and legend_text from the plot *)
leg = plot[[2,1]],
(* by default, all plots are visible (not transparent) *) 
trans = Table[False, {Length[plot[[2,1,1,1]]]}]
}, 
Dynamic[
(* dynamically re-evaluate the plot with dynamic PlotStyles and PlotLegends *)
plotfnc @@ {f, args,
(* prepend the directives with Transparent on dynamic switches *)
PlotStyle -> 
     Table[With[{i = i}, Flatten[Directive[If[TrueQ[trans[[i]]], 
          Transparent, Directive[]], leg[[1,1,i]]], 1, Directive]], 
      {i, Length[leg[[1,1]]]}],
(* turn the legend_text's into Togglers and shove them back into the *)
(* LineLegend structure.  Also, delete the old directives in the     *)
(* LineLegend structure to force PlotLegends to pick up the new      *)
(* directives, so legend lines turn on/off with the curves           *)
PlotLegends -> ReplacePart[leg, 
      Join[{{1, 1} -> Sequence[]}, Table[With[{i = i}, {1, 2, i} -> 
          Toggler[Dynamic[trans[[i]]], {True -> leg[[1,2,i]], 
            False -> leg[[1,2,i]]}, FrameMargins -> 0]], 
        {i, Length[leg[[1,2]]]}]]], FilterRules[{opts}, 
     Except[{PlotStyle, PlotLegends}]]}, 
(* only need dynamic updates when trans is modified  *)          
TrackedSymbols :> {trans}]]]
```

This solution has a known issue with `PlotLegends->Automatic`; the `Toggler` function intercepts the mouse click so the placeholder is not editable.

Comment: +1 Great work! I have one suggestion: Can the Toggler be applied not just to the legend text, but the line markers as well?

Comment: @Ajasja the line markers, or colour swatches (if you had them as an alternative) can be wrapped in `EventHandler` to facilitate toggling.

Comment: @Ajasja That was my original choice, but Mathematica 9 appears to keep the color swatches as an internal object, so I cannot wrap code around them.  The Text is all I can get to, so it had to do.

Comment: +1, nice. But it doesn't localize the plotting variable properly. Any reason we can't change the 2 `plotfnc @@ {f...` to `plotfnc[f...` and add an `Evaluate@` before the options `Evaluate@FilterRules...`?

Comment: @Rojo Good point.  That would follow better practice.  I shall have to play with that.

Answer (score 8):

The following tries to let the user use whatever `PlotStyle` and any other `Plot` options they desire.  It assumes `Plot` yields a list of directives and lines for each function plotted, in the order given in the arguments.

I seemed to run into obstacles with standard controls, so I wrote my own plus a helper function.

- `getPlotStyles` returns the directives for the plot of each function.  These are needed to make the label (used as a legend).
- `clickToggler` switches between two expressions per mouse click.  Perhaps `Toggler` could be used, but it didn't work for me.
- `makeLabel` puts together a clickable legend that turns graphs on/off.  It is a grid of `clickToggler`s.

Preliminary definitions:

```
getPlotStyles[nFuncs_, funcs_, dom_, opts___] := 
  With[{style = PlotStyle /. FilterRules[{opts}, PlotStyle]}, 
   Thread[{Table[ColorData[1][i], {i, nFuncs}], 
     If[style =!= PlotStyle, If[Head[style] === List,
       style, ConstantArray[style, nFuncs]], ConstantArray[{}, nFuncs]]}]];

clickToggler[Dynamic[x_], e_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := clickToggler[Dynamic[x], e, e, opts];
clickToggler[Dynamic[x_], on_, off_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  EventHandler[Dynamic[If[x, on, off]], {"MouseClicked" :> (x = ! x)}, opts];

makeLabel[Dynamic[display_], styles_, funcs_] := 
  With[{background = {Opacity[0], Rectangle[{-2, -1}, {2, 1}]}, 
    circleslash = {Thickness[Medium], Dashing[{}], Opacity[1], Red, Circle[], 
      Line[{{-1, -1}, {1, 1}}/Sqrt[2]]}},
   Grid[Table[With[{i = i}, (* { sample styled line, label } *)
      {Graphics[{Append[styles[[i]], {Line[{{-2, 0}, {2, 0}}], 
           clickToggler[Dynamic[display[[i]]], background, {background, circleslash}]}]},
        ImageSize -> {24, 12}, AspectRatio -> 1/2], 
       clickToggler[Dynamic[display[[i]]], 
        Panel[TraditionalForm[funcs[[i]]], Background -> White, FrameMargins -> 1]]}
     ], {i, Length@funcs}], BaseStyle -> "Label", Alignment -> {Center, Center}]];
```

`myPlot` plots the graph and has the following features:

- It is called just like `Plot` and all its arguments are passed to `Plot`, so hopefully most of `Plot`s features still work.
- It takes each graph and wraps it in a `clickToggler` (defined above) that turns the graph off if it is clicked.
- If whitespace in the plot is clicked, a menu pops up that toggles the graphs on/off.  Click away from it to make it disappear.
- It uses `Labeled` to add an interactive legend for turning graphs on/off.  Ideally either the `PlotLegend` option would be intercepted and replaced with this, or `myPlot` would have this as its own option.

The code allows for the list of functions to be wrapped by `Tooltip` etc.  The first two definitions are the way in.  The third is called by the first two.  The fourth at the very end lets a single function not in a `List` be plotted like normal, no legend, no clicking on/off.

```
SetAttributes[myPlot, HoldAll];
myPlot[wrapper_[funcs_List], rest___] := With[{n = Length[funcs]}, myPlot[n, funcs, wrapper@funcs, rest]];
myPlot[funcs_List, rest___] := With[{n = Length[funcs]}, myPlot[n, funcs, funcs, rest]];
myPlot[nFuncs_Integer, funcs_, plotargs___] := 
  DynamicModule[{
        display = ConstantArray[True, nFuncs], (* array of T/F indicating a graph is on/off *)
           plot, (* the base Plot *)
            pos, (* the positions of the group of lines making up each graph *)
         curves, (* the graphics commands making up each graph *)
         styles, (* the styles of each graph *)
      popupmenu},(* variable that toggles between the popup menu and nothing *)
    popupmenu = {}; (* popupmenu starts off blank *)
    plot = Show[Plot[plotargs], Graphics[Dynamic@popupmenu]];
    pos = DeleteDuplicates[Most /@ Position[plot, _Line, \[Infinity]]];
    curves = Extract[plot, pos];
    styles = getPlotStyles[nFuncs, plotargs];
    Labeled[
     EventHandler[Dynamic@ReplacePart[plot,
         Table[With[{i = i}, 
          pos[[i]] -> clickToggler[Dynamic[display[[i]]], curves[[i]], Line[{}], PassEventsUp -> False]],
          {i, nFuncs}]],
      {"MouseClicked" :> (popupmenu = 
          If[popupmenu === {},
            Inset[Framed[makeLabel[Dynamic[display], styles, funcs], 
             Background -> White, FrameStyle -> Thin], MousePosition["Graphics"]],
            {}])}
      ],
     makeLabel[Dynamic[display], styles, funcs],
     Right],
    SaveDefinitions -> True];
myPlot[X___] := Plot[X]; (* default to Plot *)
```

Example

```
myPlot[Tooltip@{Sin[x], Tan[2 x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 π}, PlotRange -> 2, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thick, Opacity[0.5], Directive[Brown, Thick, Dashed]}]
```

[image: All three graphs]
[image: Sine deleted]

Showing the popup menu:

[image: Popup menu]

There are many cases to test, but I only tried a few.

Comment: This is nice.  It works on pre-9 Mathematica, gives several means of turning the curves off and on, and has lots of low-level Dynamic functionality that I can take apart and learn from.  It also adds visually appealing legends to pre-9.  I wish I had this a year ago.  I actually wrote something similar, including the trick of stashing the legend text in `Tooltip`, but yours is much better.

Comment: @DanielW  Thanks.  I changed the `Module` variables to be part of the `DynamicModule`.  Now if you can save a notebook and reopen it, without recomputing the graphs.

Answer (score 7):

```
 funcs = {Sin[x], Cos[x], Tanh[x]};
 checked = ltexts = {"sin", "cos", "tanh"}; (* thanks: Ajasja *)
```

Alternative approaches:

Using`TogglerBar` as `PlotLabel` and toggling its visibility based on `CurrentValue["MouseOver"]`:

```
 Dynamic[Framed@Plot[
 funcs[[Sort[checked /. Thread[ltexts -> Range[Length[ltexts]]]]]],
 {x, 0, 3*Pi}, PlotStyle -> Thick,  Evaluated -> True,
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions",
 PlotLabel -> (If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"],
    #, Invisible@#] &[
  TogglerBar[Dynamic[checked], ltexts, Appearance -> "Button"]])]]
```

[image]

Or, `Overlay`ing  `Plot` and `TooglerBar`, toggling visibility of the latter based on `CurrentValue["MouseOver"]`:

```
 Dynamic@Overlay[{If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"],
 TogglerBar[Dynamic[checked], ltexts, Appearance -> "Button"], ""],
 Dynamic[ Plot[funcs[[Sort[ checked /. Thread[ltexts -> Range[Length[ltexts]]]]]], 
 {x, 0, 3*Pi},  PlotStyle -> Thick,
 Evaluated -> True,
 ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, 40}},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]]},
  All, 1, Alignment -> {Center, Top}]
```

Comment: Your examples do not work out of the box. Using `checked = ltexts = {"sin", "cos", "tanh"};` fixes the problem.

Comment: @Ajasja, thank you, good observation.  I missed the need for initializing `checked`. I will update with the fix.

Answer (score 3):

FYI, you can use TogglerBar and other controls in Manipulate:

```
funcs = {Sin[x], Cos[x], Tanh[x]};
Manipulate[
 Plot[fs, {x, 0, 3 Pi}],
 {fs, funcs, ControlType -> TogglerBar}]
```

[image]

`Appearance -> "Vertical", ControlPlacement -> Left`:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In a similar vein as [a previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7790/how-to-change-color-dynamically/15298#15298) this changes the color without the need to redraw the plot.

I don't have v9 so I used buttons instead of legends, it is probably easy to adapt this to `PlotLegends`

The idea is to first plot the functions with unique colors, in the resulting `Graphics` those colors are replaced with `Dynamic`-wrapped `Opacity[1,color]` and the buttons switch the 0 to 1 and 1 to 0.

```
Attributes[togglePlot] = {HoldAll};
togglePlot[funcs_, range_] := Module[
  {initcolors, p},
  (* Some unique colors *)
  initcolors = Hue /@ Range[1/Length[funcs], 1, 1/Length[funcs]];
  p = Plot[funcs, range, PlotStyle -> initcolors];

  DynamicModule[{
    (* Actual colors used *)
    colors = Opacity[1, ColorData[1][#]] & /@ Range[Length[funcs]],
    q},
   Column@{
     p /.Table[With[{i = i}, 
        initcolors[[i]] -> Dynamic[colors[[i]]]], {i, 1, Length[funcs]}],
     ButtonBar[MapIndexed[(#1 :> Function[{},
           colors[[First@#2, 1]] = colors[[First@#2, 1]] /. {0 -> 1, 1 -> 0}]) &, funcs]]}
   ]]

togglePlot[{Sin[x], Cos[x], Tan[x]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 1):

This is just a small addendum to show that one can use the whole plot to switch between the individual functions. By clicking anywhere in the figure, it toggles through the curves one-by-one, and then shows all of them again.

This has some drawbacks (like the necessity to specify an absolute `PlotRange`, assign styles to individual curves to keep coloring consistent, and wrapping singleton legends in lists) but these are usually there if one devotes so much time for visualization that even invents a new interface...

```
funcs = {Sin[x], Cos[x], Tanh[x]};
style = Thread[funcs -> {{Thick, Blue}, {Thick, Red}, {Thick, Green}}];    
switch = 0;

EventHandler[
 Dynamic[Plot[
   Evaluate@Part[funcs, switch /. (0 -> All)], {x, 0, 3 Pi},
   PlotStyle -> (Part[funcs, switch /. (0 -> All)] /. style),
   PlotRange -> {{0, 3 Pi}, {-1, 1}},
   PlotRangePadding -> .1,
   PlotLegends -> Flatten@{Part[funcs, switch /. (0 -> All)]}
   ], TrackedSymbols :> {switch}],
 {"MouseClicked" :> If[switch == Length@funcs, switch = 0, switch++]}]
```

[image: toggler plot]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple idea: Use the built-in Drawing Tools on the displayed plot to highlight a curve.

First click on the graphic to select it.

Then double-click on the desired curve to select it (this turned it orange).

Finally double-click again to highlight it (for my plot, this thickened the now-orange curve).

Background info: in Help menu, see tutorial/InteractiveGraphicsSelecting and tutorial/InteractiveGraphicsPalette