# Is it possible to select outliers on a graph and determine the index of the outliers?

Tags: plotting, graphics, dynamic

I have a large data set of experimental data for which I have determined a theoretical fit. However, for some of the experimental data I took, there was systematic error, leading to the data deviating from the expected fit as shown below (experimental values are plotted on x-axis and theoretical values are plotted on y-axis).

[image: graph of data and outliers]

Is it possible to write some code to allow one to simply click on the outliers and determine their index, or is there any way to do so natively in Mathematica?

It would also be possible for me to divide the values plotted on the y-axis by those plotted on the x-axis, but I'm wondering whether there's a general method allowing you to click on to identify outliers on any graph.

My code for the graph is as follows (I'm only plotting the first 500 values):

```
Show[ListPlot[Prepend[Transpose[{experimentalCR[[1 ;; 500]], 
 theoreticalCR[[1 ;; 500]]}], {0, 0}]], ImageSize -> {500, 500}, AspectRatio -> Full]
```

A sample of the data can be found here: http://pastebin.com/mA6VxPfw

Comment: @Chris Degnen you're a genius.
Thanks a lot!
could you specify some references for the method that you have used?

Comment: @meriens I'm not sure if Chris will see the comment here. Perhaps you should post it at his answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might like to try `Tooltip`:

```
mixeddata = 
  Prepend[Transpose[{experimentalCR[[1 ;; 500]], 
     theoreticalCR[[1 ;; 500]]}], {0, 0}];

ListPlot[Table[
  Tooltip[mixeddata[[i + 1]], i], {i, Length@mixeddata - 1}], 
 ImageSize -> {500, 500}, AspectRatio -> Full]
```

Or equivalently:

```
 ListPlot[MapThread[
  Tooltip[#1, #2] &, {mixeddata, Range[0, Length@mixeddata - 1]}], 
 ImageSize -> {500, 500}, AspectRatio -> Full]
```

The graphic is the same, so I won't show it here: the tooltips won't show, after all. The reason I used the index specification that I do is because of that {0,0} you prepreded. If you had added it at the end, this wouldn't have been needed. As kguler's answer shows, you can put anything in the `Tooltip`.

As another aside, you don't need the `Show`, you can just apply the desired options (`AspectRatio` etc) directly in the `ListPlot`.

As for *identifying* the outliers, it depends what constitutes outliers in your dataset. For cases like yours with experimental data and theoretical data, here are some suggestions based on styling the individual points. In the each graph, redder dots are greater outliers.

```
Row[{ListPlot[
   Style[{##}, Blend[{Red, Black}, (#2/#1)^8]] & @@@ (Rest@mixeddata),
    ImageSize -> 300, AspectRatio -> 1], 
  ListPlot[Style[{##}, 
      Hue[1, 1 - (#2/#1)^4, 0.9 - (#2/#1)^8]] & @@@ (Rest@mixeddata), 
   ImageSize -> 300, AspectRatio -> 1]}]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer! actually, I prepended the {0,0} because I wanted to force the graph to display the origin - is there any better way to do this?

Comment: @VincentTjeng PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}

Comment: @belisarius thank you. I'm horrible at searching through documentation.

Answer (score 8):

This method uses [single prediction confidence intervals](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/StatisticalModelAnalysis.html) to determine and select outliers.  The confidence levels are set to 1, 2 and 3 standard deviations.  The points outside 3 SD can be found in `o3` and the points outside 1 SD can be found in `o1` and `o3` combined.  The points in `o1` and `o3` are plotted in the chart in green and red respectively.

```
data = Transpose@{experimentalCR, theoreticalCR};
{mx, my} = 1.1*Max /@ {experimentalCR, theoreticalCR};

{sd1, sd2, sd3} = 
  2*(CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], #] - 0.5) & /@ {1, 2, 3};

lm = LinearModelFit[data, {1, x }, x];

getseries[sd_] := Module[{cb},
  cb = lm["SinglePredictionBands", ConfidenceLevel -> sd];
  {lower, upper} = Transpose[cb /. x -> # & /@ experimentalCR];
  p1 = Position[
    MapThread[#1 <= #2 <= #3 &, {lower, theoreticalCR, upper}], True];
  Extract[data, p1]]

s3 = getseries[sd3];
o3 = Complement[data, s3];

s1 = getseries[sd1];
o1 = Complement[s3, s1];

{bands68[x_], bands95[x_], bands99[x_]} = Table[lm["SinglePredictionBands",
    ConfidenceLevel -> cl], {cl, {sd1, sd2, sd3}}];
Show[ListPlot[data],
 Plot[{lm[x], bands68[x], bands95[x], bands99[x]},
  {x, 0, mx}, Filling -> {2 -> {1}, 3 -> {2}, 4 -> {3}}],
 ListPlot[o1, PlotStyle -> Directive[Green, PointSize[Large]]],
 ListPlot[o3, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]],
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> {{0, mx}, {0, my}},
 ImageSize -> 480, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

**Edit**

It seems appropriate to add an alternative method, (although the data in this case does not suggest the suitability of a multivariate fit):-

```
data = Transpose@{experimentalCR, theoreticalCR};
prange = Sort[#][[{1, -1}]] & /@ {experimentalCR, theoreticalCR};

{{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}} = {#1, #2*1.35} & @@@ prange;
(* For values within two standard deviations,(approx 95.45% of values) *)
sd = 2;
cl = 2*(CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], sd] - 0.5);
Needs["MultivariateStatistics`"];
e = EllipsoidQuantile[data, cl];
ctr = e[[1]];
{r1, r2} = e[[2]];
inc = ArcTan[e[[3, 1, 2]]/e[[3, 1, 1]]]*180/Pi;
Print["Ellipse center = " <> ToString@ctr];
Print["Ellipse radii (r1, r2) = " <> ToString@{r1, r2}]; Print[
 StringJoin["Ellipse inclination = ", ToString@inc, " degrees"]];

(* Find the foci of the ellipse *)
f = Sqrt[r1^2 - r2^2];
dx = f*Cos[inc Degree];
dy = f*Sin[inc Degree];
f1 = ctr - {dx, dy};
f2 = ctr + {dx, dy};

edge = ctr + r1*e[[3, 1]];
rlim = EuclideanDistance[edge, f1] + EuclideanDistance[edge, f2];
(* nod to belisarius here *)
inside[{x_, y_}, {f1_, f2_}] := 
  Sum[EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, i], {i, {f1, f2}}];
sd = Select[data, inside[#, {f1, f2}] < rlim &];

Show[RegionPlot[inside[{x, y}, {f1, f2}] < rlim,
  {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}],
 ListPlot[data], Graphics[{Green, Point@sd}],
 Graphics@e,
 Graphics[{Black, Thick, Dashing[0.05],
   Rotate[Circle[ctr, {r1, r2}], inc Degree]}],
 Graphics[{Red, Line[{ctr + r1*e[[3, 1]], ctr, ctr + r2*e[[3, 2]]}]}],
 Graphics[{Yellow, PointSize[Large], Point[{f1, f2}]}],
 PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}},
 AspectRatio -> (ymax - ymin)/(xmax - xmin), ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

Comment: hi @Chris, what's your reason behind choosing an ellipse here? If i understand correctly, points are considered to be outliers by your program if and only if they lie outside the ellipse. However, assuming that the graph is one of theoretical against experimental values, wouldn't the points have to lie on a line, as in the first part of your explanation?

Comment: @Vincent - included it for general reference, (outlier identification).

Comment: I see. thank you!

Answer (score 6):

From a related Q/A: [Extracting the coordinate of a particular point of interest from a ListPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16925/125)

```
   data = RandomReal[100, {200, 2}];
   ListPlot[Tooltip[data[[#]],
   Column[{Row[{"index: ", # }],
    Row[{"values: ", data[[#]]}],
    Row[{"ratio: ", data[[#]][[2]]/data[[#]][[1]]}]}, Center]] & /@
    Range[Length[data]], PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium]]
```

[image]

Or, replace `Tooltip` by `PopupWindow` in the above code to get

[image]

Comment: thank you for the well-explained answer! both you and Verbeia have come up with a great answer that really helps me. However, is there any simple way to click on the data point and add its index to a list which we can extract later? I'm not sure how to extract the index.

Comment: @VincentTjeng, please check "Update 2" in [the linked Q/A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16925/125) for an example that does something quite similar.

Comment: got it, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Look at my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20112/how-to-dynamically-toggle-curves-on-off-in-a-crowded-plot) where I use `Annotation[...,"Mouse"]` and `MouseAnnotation[]` to get the index of a curve that is clicked on in a plot.  The same technique could be applied to individual data points in a `LineListPlot[...,Joined->False]`.  It will not work with `ListPlot`, which is an older function that does not support `Annotation`.

Comment: Thank you, looks like something I should try.