# How to Toggle Points on and Off

Tags: plotting, manipulate

The code below is a snippet of some large code that I am working on.  I want the points in the code below to appear and disappear when selecting the toggle box "points".  I do not want to use the opacity or flipview techniques found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101475/easy-code-to-toggle-between-a-graph-and-a-blank-graph).   They are not optimal when used with the rest of my code.  I tried the following and used "" as in the same link above... but it doesn't work.  Any suggestions?

```
Manipulate[
 ListPointPlot3D[
  If[b, {{0, 0, 3}, {0, 3, 0}, {3, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -3}, {0, -3, 0}, {-3,
      0, 0}}, ""]],
 {{b, True, "points"}, {True, False}}]
```

Comment: If you put some points instead of "" then it flips fine. The problem is you have to make ListPlot3D happy by giving it something to plot.

Comment: @bill s   Yes... I understand.  However, I would like to keep the space visible with no points visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm surprised that `ListPointPlot3D[{}, PlotRange -> ...]` does not work. `ListPlot[{}]` works and so should `ListPointPlot3D`, I think.

An OK solution: You have to be able to calculate the plot range though.

```
Manipulate[
 If[b,
  plot = ListPointPlot3D[{{0, 0, 3}, {0, 3, 0}, {3, 0, 0}, {0, 
      0, -3}, {0, -3, 0}, {-3, 0, 0}}],
  Graphics3D[{}, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}, 
   Options[plot]]
  ],
 {{b, True, "points"}, {True, False}},
 {plot, ControlType -> None}]
```

There's a slight wiggle because `Options[plot]` does not give the correct padding for the vertical axis.

This works perfectly, but uses an undocumented function:

```
Manipulate[
 If[b,
  plot = ListPointPlot3D[{{0, 0, 3}, {0, 3, 0}, {3, 0, 0}, {0, 
      0, -3}, {0, -3, 0}, {-3, 0, 0}}],
  Graphics3D[{}, PlotRange -> Charting`get3DPlotRange@plot, 
   PlotRangePadding -> None, Options[plot]]
  ],
 {{b, True, "points"}, {True, False}},
 {plot, ControlType -> None},
 TrackedSymbols :> {b}]
```

The `TrackedSymbols` options does not seem to be necessary in this simple example, but it might be in a more complicated application.

Slightly more efficient, if the code structure of the actual use-case allows for it:

```
data = RandomReal[{-3, 3}, {10000, 3}];
Manipulate[
 With[{plot = ListPointPlot3D[data]},
  Dynamic@ If[b,
    plot,
    Graphics3D[{}, PlotRange -> Charting`get3DPlotRange@plot, 
     PlotRangePadding -> None, Options[plot]]
    ]
  ],
 {{b, True, "points"}, {True, False}}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Does this work for you?

```
b = True;
pts = {{0, 0, 3}, {0, 3, 0}, {3, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -3}, {0, -3, 0}, {-3, 
    0, 0}};
l = ListPointPlot3D@pts;
Dynamic[p = If[b, pts, {{0, 0, 20}}];
 Checkbox[Dynamic[b], {False, True}]]
Dynamic@Quiet@
  ListPointPlot3D[p, PlotRange -> MinMax /@ Transpose@pts, 
   PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1], PlotTheme -> "Marketing"]
```

[image]