# Plot many curves on the same graph

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, functions, visualization

This plot has 40 curves on the same graph which makes it hard to see. 
I need to plot them on one graph. So I have an idea to plot to make it easier to see which one is larger or smaller in each range. 
The idea is that to plot them and each one is linked with a radio button or something so that you can look at the graph and decide to hide or unhide any curve you want to make it easier to compare.

How can I implement this? Would it be possible to make it hide with gray color instead of completely invisible?
Or is there any other idea? 
The function below is just for this example. My real function is more complex.

```
f[a_, b_, c_] := (a*x^2 + b*x + c)/3;
tup1 := RandomInteger[5, {40, 3}];
Plot[f[##] & @@@ tup1 // Evaluate, {x, 0, 5}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

Comment: @cvgmt it's still difficult to compare as two many curves. My idea is that once it's plot I can look at each curve and decide hide curves that are not interested.

Comment: [A related question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20112)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Update 2:** We can combine a toggler-bar legend and `FlipView` to control curve visibility by clicking on curves and/or legends. (Naturally this approach is less responsive than either method.)

```
f[a_, b_, c_] := (a x^2 + b x + c)/3;

tup1 := RandomInteger[5, {40, 3}];

tup = tup1;

functions = f @@@ tup;

colors = ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length @ functions];

functionswithtooltips = MapThread[Tooltip, {functions, tup}];
```

First we plot `functionswithtooltips` and extract the primitives:

```
plot1 = Plot[Evaluate[functionswithtooltips], {x, 0, 5}, 
   GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large, 
   PlotStyle -> Thread[Directive[colors, Opacity[.3], Thin]]];
ttlist = Cases[plot1, _Tooltip, All];
```

**Note:** In versions 13.3+, add the option `PlotHighlighting -> None` in definition of `plot1` above.

Then we turn each tooltipped line into an [`EventHandler`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EventHandler.html) and add the necessary updating to dynamic variables:

```
Deploy @ DynamicModule[{n = {1}, hidden = ConstantArray[1, Length @ ttlist]},
  hidden[[n]] = 2; 
  Dynamic[Legended[
    Graphics[Table[With[{i = i, ind = hidden[[i]]}, 
       Tooltip[{ttlist[[i, 1, 1]], 
         DynamicModule[{boxes = {ttlist[[i, 1, 2]], 
             Style[ttlist[[i, 1, 2]], Opacity[1], Thickness[Large]]}, 
           index = ind, length = 2}, 
          EventHandler[Dynamic[boxes[[index]]], 
            {"MouseClicked" :> (index = index /. {1 -> 2, 2 -> 1}; 
                  hidden[[i]] = index; n = Flatten[Position[hidden, 2]];), 
             Method -> "Preemptive",
             PassEventsDown -> True, PassEventsUp -> True}], 
          DynamicModuleValues :> {}]}, 
       ttlist[[i, 2]]]], {i, 1, Length @ ttlist}], 
     ImageSize -> 700, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 50}}, Frame -> True],
    TogglerBar[Dynamic[n, (n = #; hidden[[All]] = 1; hidden[[n]] = 2) &], 
     MapIndexed[
       #2[[1]] -> Style[#, 16, Bold, Opacity[1], colors[[#2[[1]]]]] &, tup],
     Appearance -> "Vertical" -> {Automatic, 4}]]]]
```

[image]

**Update:** We can use [`FlipView`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FlipView.html) to interactively hide/show a curve:

```
plot1 = Plot[Evaluate[functionswithtooltips], {x, 0, 5}, 
   GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large, 
   PlotStyle -> Thread[Directive[colors, Opacity[.3], Thin]]];

plot1 /. l_Line :> 
   FlipView[{l, Style[l, Opacity[1], Thick]}] // Deploy
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

You can use `TogglerBar` as legend panel to hide/show any subset of lines:

```
f[a_, b_, c_] := (a x^2 + b x + c)/3;
tup1 := RandomInteger[5, {40, 3}];

tup = tup1;
functions = f @@@ tup;

colors = ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length @ functions];

Dynamic[Legended[Plot[functions, {x, 0, 5}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
    ImageSize -> Large, 
    PlotStyle -> ReplacePart[colors, {Except[Alternatives @@ n]} -> None]], 
  TogglerBar[Dynamic[n], 
     MapIndexed[
        #2[[1]] -> Style[#,16, Bold, Opacity[1], colors[[#2[[1]]]]] &, tup],
   Appearance -> "Vertical" -> {Automatic, 4}]]]
```

[image]

You can  add tooltips and play with opacity and thickness rather than making lines completely invisible:

```
functionswithtooltips = MapThread[Tooltip, {functions, tup}];

DynamicModule[{n = {1}}, 
 Dynamic[Legended[Plot[Evaluate @ functionswithtooltips , {x, 0, 5}, 
    GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large, 
    PlotStyle -> (Thread[Directive[colors, Opacity[.3], Thin]] /. 
       Directive[a : Alternatives @@ colors[[n]], _, _] :> 
        Directive[a, Opacity[1], AbsoluteThickness[3]])], 
   TogglerBar[Dynamic[n], 
    MapIndexed[
      #2[[1]] -> Style[#, 16, Bold, Opacity[1], colors[[#2[[1]]]]] &, tup],
    Appearance -> "Vertical" -> {Automatic, 4}]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: very nice figure

Comment: Would it be possible to select a curve on the graph and it shows me which parameter combination is it on the right too?

Comment: Thanks. That is same as what I was thinking . Would it be OK to highlight the  parameter combination somehow so when I click on a curve and if I want to hide it then I can immediately locate its location to hide? Current version is nice too. Just thinking if that can be done easily from this.

Comment: @anhnha, please see the update.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's really nice. I'm still learning the code. The original is great too but the only problem is that when I look at a curve in the graph I know its parameter like `{0,1,5}` but then in order to hide/unhide it I have to search through the parameter table to know the position of it.

Comment: To hide/unhide a curve has some issue when two many curves are very close or are almost the same.

Comment: @anhnha, I am not sure if there is any clean solution when many curves are almost the same ... (except, maybe, to play with `ImageSize` and/or `PlotRange` to make the lines visually distinguishable).

Comment: What does `PlotStyle -> ReplacePart[colors, {Except[Alternatives @@ n]} -> None]` do in the original code?

Comment: @anhnha, for, say `colors = {Red, Green, Blue, Magenta, Orange}` and `n = {2,4}`, `ReplacePart[colors, {Except[Alternatives @@ n]} -> None]`, replaces parts  1, 3 and 5 of colors with `None` to produce `{None, Green, None, Blue, None}` and `PlotStyle ->{None, Green, None, Blue, None, None}` causes `Plot` to show only the 2nd and 4th functions (with colors `Green` and `Blue`, respectively) and hide the rest.

Comment: Thanks. How can I change `None` to something like `Gray` with `Opacity[0.3]`. I don't know how to combine both properties for this.

Comment: @anhnha, replace `None` with `Opacity[.3, Gray]` or with `Directive[Opacity[.3], Gray]`.

Comment: Yeah, that works. Is `ColorData[97]` the best one for contrasting colors?

Comment: Also how can I put more space between the graph and the parameter set table?

Comment: @anhnha, not sure which color scheme has the best contrast (that sounds like a good new question). To put more space between _plot_ and _legend_ in `Legended[plot, legend]`  you can use `Legended[plot, Row[{Spacer[10], legend}]]` and play with different values instead of 10.

Answer (score 1):

Just a list of other alternatives (as only a toy example is given in the above question):

- When one has many curves one might consider plotting all possible
  pairwise plots of the parameters as the "information" about the
  curves is complete contained in those parameters (if we ignore the
  error variance for the moment).  Each point could be labeled as to
  its source.
- If there are many parameters, then other summary statistics that make
  some sort of subject matter sense could be plotted against each
  other.  For example, if dealing with insecticides and a logistic
  regression, then plotting the LD50 (Lethal Dose that kills 50% of the
  critters) and the LD95 against each other might be a good and compact
  summary that makes sense to those subject matter experts.  (This matches the OP's statement "So I have an idea to plot to make it easier to see which one is larger or smaller in each range.".)