# Is it possible to have a plot inside a manipulate with parametric controls?

Tags: manipulate

As the title suggests, I am trying to use a `Plot` inside a `Manipulate` which has its controls defined programmatically. Mathematica doesn't plot anything and gives me no error, so I don't know what else to do.

I have create a simplified example of my problem (my original program is more complex):

```
Manipulate[
 Evaluate[
  Plot[{a[1] + a[2] x}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLabel -> {a[1], a[2]}]
  ]
 ,
 Evaluate[
  Sequence @@ ({{a[#], 1, Subscript[a, #]}, Range[3], 
       ControlType -> SetterBar} & /@ Range[2])
  ]
 ]
```

As you can see by playing with this program, the label of the `Plot` does update, but the `Plot` is empty.

Any help will be much appreciated. (And I'm sorry if this is a duplicate question; I've tried many of the solutions on similar questions, many of them using `With`, but I couldn't make the `Plot` appear and I'm frustrated now. Maybe you can help me?)

---

**Edit:**

This could be an updated example (it is very close to what I have and am trying to do):

```
DynamicModule[{f},
 f = {x, x^2};
 Manipulate[
  Plot[Pick[f, a /@ Range[2]], {x, 0, 1}, PlotLabel -> {a[1], a[2]}]
  ,
  Evaluate[
   Sequence @@ ({{a[#], True, Subscript[a, #]}, {True, False}} & /@ 
      Range[2])
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

In essence, I have an arbitrary-length list of curves I'd like to plot (so I need to be able to program how many controls appear: one per curve) but also I want to be able to select which of those curves are plotted (which is the purpose of the controls). I hope this makes sense (English is not my main language).

---

**Final edit:**

As a token of my thanks to all those helping me, I have created an example that merges all the wisdom shared on the answers. Thank you very much to all of you!

```
DynamicModule[{n = 3, f, a, po},
 f = x^# & /@ Range[n];
 With[{
   arange = a /@ Range[n]
   },
  Manipulate[
   po = Flatten@Position[arange, True];
   Plot[
    Evaluate@Pick[f, arange], {x, 0, 1},
    PlotLabel -> po,
    PlotStyle -> (ColorData[97] /@ Range[n])[[po]]
    ]
   
   ,
   Evaluate[
    Row[{
      Sequence @@ (Control[{{a[#], True, Subscript[a, #]}, {True, 
             False}}] & /@ Range[n])
      }, Spacer[20]]
    ]
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

This is what I was looking for, I spent three days trying on my own, and you help me achieve it in a few minutes. Thank you!

Comment: Remove the Evaluate from around your Plot.

Comment: Thank you, Lericr. Now the example does plot. Unfortunately, this only means that my example is not a reflection of my problem (if I remove the ```Evaluate``` from my original program if doesn't work). I'll try to come up with a better (although longer) example. But it will have to be tomorrow.

Comment: Well, I couldn't let it go, so I have updated my question with a second version of the code. This time it is much closer to what I have.

Comment: closely related Q/A: [Plot many curves on the same graph](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/239609/125)

Comment: Thank you, kglr, for the link. I will have to study it more closely as they created many cool things I would like to implement on my ```Plot```s. But the plot itself was just another example for my bigger (hidden) question: is there a way to programmatically create controls in any situation (not just for a single plot)? And the answer is yes, and I've learned to do it. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either change the first `Plot` argument to

```
Pick[f, {a[1], a[2]}]
```

or inject the `a`'s:

```
DynamicModule[{f}, f = {x, x^2};
 With[{arange = a /@ Range[2]},
  Manipulate[
   Plot[
    Pick[f, arange],
    {x, 0, 1},
    PlotLabel -> {a[1], a[2]}],
   Evaluate[
    Sequence @@ ({{a[#], True, Subscript[a, #]}, {True, False}} & /@ 
       Range[2])]]]
 ]
```

Someone on this site once said, "`Manipulate` is a strange beast."  It rewrites your code in ways that don't always respect the way the ordinary kernel-based Mathematica works.  In this case, the control variables need to be rewritten so they can be instantiated as front-end dynamic-module variables in a way that no matter how many times you paste the output, you always get new "localized" variables.

In this case it's `a[1]` and `a[2]` that are given new variable names. They no longer have the head `a`, and the `a` in `a /@ Range[2]` does not refer to these new variables.

Comment: One might think `LocalizeVariables -> False` would solve this problem (at the risk of making `a` global). But alas, `a[1]` and `a[2]` are localized anyway. I guess `Manipulate` really does not like indexed variables all that much. At least it allows code construction like the OP's

Comment: Thank you very much, Michael! Your answer (inject the ```a```s) was exactly what I was looking for. Maybe Bob's approach (use a ```TogglerBar ``` ) could be easier for the vast majority of my new projects, but in the application I'm working on right now it is not possible to use it. Yours, on the other hand, is perfect!! I will wait a few days to accept yours as the final answer, in case someone else has a better solution. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @RoberRM You're welcome. I was principally trying to explain how to fix your approach and why your initial ideas ran into trouble with `Manipulate`, so that you might better understand how `Manipulate` works. For simple things, `Manipulate` is great. For more involved programming problems, like indexed variables, there are tricky pitfalls in what `Manipulate` does to make the simple things simple. The more familiar you are with the available tools, such as `TogglerBar`, the easier it becomes to keep things simple.

Comment: Definitely, Michael! I appreciate very much the explanations you gave me and the two options you wrote. And I will certainly try to use simpler solutions when available, so thank you for the advice (I'll add ```ToggleBar``` to my collection of tools too).

Answer (score 8):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f = x^Range[5];
```

[`TogglerBar`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TogglerBar.html) enables choosing any or all functions for plotting.

```
Manipulate[
 funcs = If[funcs === {}, {1}, Sort[funcs]];
 Plot[Evaluate[f[[funcs]]], {x, 0, 1},
  PlotStyle -> (ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length[f]])[[funcs]],
  PlotLegends -> Placed[f[[funcs]], {.25, .7}]],
 {{funcs, Range[1, Length[f], 2], "functions"},
  Thread[Range[Length[f]] -> f],
  ControlType -> TogglerBar}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, Bob! Although this was not my initial question (as I wanted to learn how to create controls programatically that worked in every situation) you have taught me something new and very cool and I'll be sure to try your approach with ```ToogleBar``` in the future. Also, I love (and am amazed) at how well (and quickly) you write code that takes into account many situations (for example, the user deselecting all toggles). Congratulations on that! And thank you again!!